# XElement to get all sub-element node names and values

Tags: c#, xmldocument, xelement, selectnodes

I'm thinking of an approach something like this.
Please let me know if this can actually work this way:
For Sample XML:

```
<Root>
  <Node>
    <SubEl1>abc</SubEl1>
    <SubEl2>def</SubEl2>
    <SubEl3>123</SubEl3>
    <SubEl4>456</SubEl4>      
  </Node>
</Root>
```

Want to go  into `<Node>`, loop through check for the node/element name and get it's value. 
Something like this, say name is 'SubEl1' use 'abc' for task1, on seeing the element name is 'SubEl2' I do task2. All sub-elements have to be checked for!

Example (not working code):

```
 //looping through 'Node' children
        switch(SubElName for 'Node element) 
        {
          case : 'SubEl1' 
            //Do Task1 using the SubEl1's value/TextName ...
          case: 'SubEl2' 
           //Task2 ...
          ... 
          case: default //Do default task.....
        } 
    //end loop
```

If you can think of any other approach (XElement, XmlDocument, SelectNodes() etc., that will be appreciated too!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For this task it looks like all you need to do is simply create a list/dictionary of the node name and the node value, you then can use that in your switch....

```
var list = from x in XElement.Load(**yourxmlfile**).Element("Node").Elements()
           select new
           {
              Name = x.Name,
              Value = (string)x
           };
```

now you have a list of Name, value pairs you can simply pass to your switch method.

Comment: Up voted your solution as it actually provides implementation (=

Comment: thank you it works just used the switch too! I know LINQ is great, but the syntax takes time getting  used to. you must be a genius.

Comment: :-) no, no genius. It's just takes a little practice to get used to the syntax...it really is worth the learning curve though.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't made a use of it yet but LINQ to XML looks like all kinds of awesome.  Here are some links.
[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx)
[Hooked On LINQ](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoXML5MinuteOverview.ashx)

Comment: Linq to XML <b>is</b> all kinds of Awesome.

Answer (score 0):

use http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb342765.aspx to get all children and http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.name.aspx to check for the name.